# Scrapy Crawl a link only once

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

Is it possible in scrapy to crawl a url which contains 'hello' only once and continue scraping rest of the urls and follow them ?

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to read the documentation to understand how Scrapy works?  Do you know Python?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the documentation. I have tried defining rules for the same as below but no luck
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('login_form'), unique=True), callback="parse_url", follow=True), Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('hello)), callback="parse_url"),)

I am not getting where I am hgoing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class level boolean variable and set it to `False` by default. Then, after crawling the url containing `hello`, set it to `True`. Something like this:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    hello_crawled = False

    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        if 'hello' in response.url:
            if self.hello_crawled:
                return
            else:
                self.hello_crawled = True
        ...
```

Comment: alexce : But I don't want that the parse function is again called. Is there a way that once hello is caught in the link it can be dynamically updated in the CrawlSpider rules ?

Comment: @user2722127 yeah, this is some sort of a workaround, does it work for you? Not sure if you can change the rules on the fly.

Comment: this type of workaround works but for website were there are quite a many links which conatin 'hello' is quite of a time consuming task for me.
So thought might be there a better solution than the approach I am using